# How do I get stored dictionaries' values from a shelve-file back into the program

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, shelve

I started learning Python 2 weeks ago, and now I am trying to code a text adventure game. However, I've run into a problem. So far, I haven't found any solution on Google which can help me.

I decided to store basically all relevant variables in dictionaries - feel free to tell me wether that's even a clever idea or rather stupid of me, I actually do not know this, I just thought it might be a solution that works.

**Here's my problem:** last thing I decided to insert into the program is a `save_game()` function. So I defined:

```
def save_game(data):
    import shelve
    savegame = shelve.open('./save/savegame')
    savegame['data'] = data
    savegame.close()
```

And of course, if I then call

```
save_game(save_game_data)
```

with `save_game_data` being the dictionary where I've put all the other dictionaries so I can handle saving with a single function call (I thought that might be better?), it actually works.

But of course a `save_game()` only makes sense if you can also reload the data into the program.
So I defined:

```
def load_game(data):
    import shelve, time
    savegame = shelve.open('./save/savegame')
    data = savegame['data']
    data = dict(data) # This was inserted because I hoped it would solve my problem, but it doesn't
    savegame.close()
```

But the result of

```
load_game(save_game_data)
```

Unfortunately is no updated dictionary `save_game_data` with all the keys and values, and I just can't get my head around how to get all the stored data back into values in the dictionaries. Maybe I'm on a totally wrong way all together, maybe I just don't know enough about Python yet to even know where I'm erring.

The `save_game()` and `load_game()` functions are in a different file from the main file, and are correctly imported if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass `save_game_data` to `load_game()` as if to mean "load data and put it into `save_game_data`" but this isn't what `load_game()` is doing. By doing this:

```
def load_game(data):
    import shelve, time
    savegame = shelve.open('./save/savegame')
    data = (savegame['data'])
```

You're replacing what `data` refers to, so `save_game_data` doesn't get changed.

Instead, you can drop the argument to `load_game()` and add:

```
return data
```

at the end of the function, and call it like this:

```
save_game_data = load_game()
```

Comment: OMG, it actually was something really small I couldn't figure out. Thank you so much, that helps a ton :) Now I can continue wasting lots of time fiddling around with the code that I most likely should rather invest in reading more chapters beforehand ^.^'